# alert with jquery for multi table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
$columns = array('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd');
$num_cols = count(columns);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach($columns as $col)
{
   echo "<td>$col</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

for($i=1;$i<4;$i++)
{
   echo "<tr>";
   for($j=0;$j<$num_cols;$j++)
   {
      echo "<td class='click' from=???>$i</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

this generated for me:

```
aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd
 1  |  1  |  1  |  1 
 2  |  2  |  2  |  2 
 3  |  3  |  3  |  3
```

i would like add for this alert jquery - if i click for example *2 from aaa* i have receive alert (2 from a);

i use jquery:

```
$(".click").click(function(){
   alert($(this).html + "from" + ???);
})
```

is this possible?

Comment: Should it be `$num_cols = count($columns);` at `line 2`. You are missing `$` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that `html` is a function.  Also, `on` is the preferred way to add events as of jQuery 1.7

I would put your header cells in `<th>` tags, then do:

```
$(document).on("click", "td", function () {
     var index = $(this).parent().find(this).index();
     alert($(this).html() + "from" + $("table th").eq(index).html());
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XETkg/6/)

---

Or, if you don't want to put your first row in `<th>` tags, this will work too:

$(document).on("click", "td", function () {
        var index = $(this).parent().find(this).index();
       alert($(this).html() + "from" + $("table tr:first td").eq(index).html());
   });

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XETkg/7/)

Answer (score 0):

And you better use this using [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/),

```
$(".click").live("click", function(){
   alert($(this).html + "from" + ???);
})
```

Comment: live id depricated bro :)  As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.